# Function not running in server

Tags: php, .htaccess, server

I move files localhost to server but not running.I put my files in subfolder (domainname/myapp),My main file is api.php.
Here is my .htaccess file,Where i am wrong ?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]   
</IfModule>
```

Comment: maybe just the subfolder is missing, like `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subfolder/api.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]` etc..

Comment: @Kazz :i already tried but not working

Comment: do you have enabled htaccess file on your server ? is module `mod_rewrite` available on your server ?

Comment: @Kazz : how can i enable this ? i am using godaddy account

Comment: on godaddy is htaccess enabled and mod_rewrite available and enabled by default... ok try just add `RewriteBase /subdir/` after `RewriteEngine On`